# Slack Reminder (/remind @group #channel "Message") not possible

Tags: slack, reminders

I wonder if someone can help me. I'd like to find a way to setup a daily reminder that will notify particular group in Slack (not the whole channel). I've been looking on the web, but wasn't able to find anything.

1. Slack does not allow send reminders to multiple users at the same time
2. Slack also does not allow to create a reminder (/remind) for the group.
   Thank you

Comment: Can you try using Slack Workflows ? They can help you depending on your use-case . https://slack.com/intl/en-in/slack-tips/workflow-builder-examples

Comment: Something like this : https://slack.com/intl/en-in/slack-tips/daily-reminder-to-post-standup-in-channel